# Differential form of local martingale and its quadratic variation

Tags: stochastic-integrals, quadratic-variation, local-martingales

I have a question regarding the differential form of a local martingale and its quadratic variation (the source of the question is p. 136-137 in [https://galton.uchicago.edu/~mykland/paperlinks/I.A.1-Econometrics_of_High_Frequency_Data.pdf](https://galton.uchicago.edu/%7Emykland/paperlinks/I.A.1-Econometrics_of_High_Frequency_Data.pdf))

Given a local martingale on the form $X_t = X_0 + \int_0^t \sigma^2_s \, dW_s$. Suppose we have a grid of time points $\mathcal{G} = \{t_1 = 0, \ldots, t_n = T \}$ on the interval $[0,T]$ and for $t \in [0,T]$ we define $t^{\ast} = \max \{ t_i \in \mathcal{G} \colon t_i \leq t \}$ and the local martingale
\begin{align} 
    M_t &= 2\sum_{t_{i+1} \leq t} \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} (X_s - X_{t_i}) \, dX_s + 2 \int^t_{t^{\ast}} (X_s - X_{t^{\ast}}) \, dX_s. \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align} 
d M_t = 2(X_t - X_{t^{\ast}}) dX_t. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}
I agree with this, because it is what I obtain by considering $M_{t + \Delta t} - M_t$ and then taking limits as $\Delta t \to 0$. My problem is the following, consider the quadratic variation of $M_t$
\begin{align*}
    [M, M]_t &= 4\sum_{t_{i+1} \leq t} \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} (X_s - X_{t_i})^2 \, d[X, X]_s + 4 \int^t_{t^{\ast}} (X_s - X_{t^{\ast}})^2 \, d[X,X]_s,
\end{align*}
then supposedly
\begin{align}
d[M,M]_t = 4(X_t - X_{t_i})^2 d[X,X]_t. \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{align}
Using that $d[X,X]_t = \sigma^2_t \, dt$ I am able to (at least I think I am) to show that
\begin{align}
d[M,M]_t = 4(X_t - X_{t^{\ast}})^2 d[X,X]_t.  \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align}
(note that (4) differs from (3) by including $t^{\ast}$ and not $t_i$) by considering $[M,M]_{t + \Delta t} - [M, M]_t$ and taking limits.
Obviously, I must be misunderstanding something, as (3) is the correct answer. What way is the correct way to show (3)?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the question. Best to edit it using `\tag{}` to number the equations and mention which exactly you understand and which you don't.

Comment: My bad! I've updated the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of $t^*$ which the authors denote by $t_*\,$ I'd rather define the left continuous step function
$$
T_t=\max\{t_i\in{\cal G}:t_i\color{red}{<}t\}
$$
by which
$$\tag{1}
M_t=2\sum_{t_{i+1}\le t}\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}(X_s-X_{t_i})\,dX_s+2\int_{T_t}^t(X_s-X_{\textstyle T_\color{red}{t}})\,dX_s
$$
can be written as
$$\tag{2}
M_t=2\int_{0}^{t}(X_s-X_{\textstyle T_\color{red}{s}})\,dX_s\,.
$$
This is possible because

- for $t_i<s\le t_{i+1}$ we have $t_i=T_s$ and
- for $T_t<s\le t$ we have $T_s=T_t\,.$

Then we get as usual
$$\tag{3}
[M,M]_t=4\int_0^t(X_s-X_{\textstyle T_\color{red}{s}})^2\,d[X,X]_s\,.
$$
If we want we could now use the bullet points to switch back to the clumsier formula
$$\tag{4}
[M,M]_t=4\sum_{t_{i+1}\le t}\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}}(X_s-X_{t_i})^2\,d[X,X]_s
+4\int_{T_t}^t(X_s-X_{\textstyle T_\color{red}{t}})^2\,d[X,X]_s\,.
$$

Comment: Thanks! My original post was unclear regarding the grid and $t^{\ast}$, I have edited it now. Your solution works either way, but I am still confused. Suppose we insert $t$ in
\begin{align*}
    d[M,M]_s &= 4 \big( X_s - \sum_{i=1}^n 1_{ \{t_i < s \leq t_{i+1} \} } X_{t_i} \big)^2 \, d[X,X]_s.
\end{align*}
If $t \in (t_k, t_{k+1})$ for some $k$ ($t$ is not in the grid), $d[M,M]_t = 4(X_t - X_{t^{\ast}})^2 d[X, X]_t$, if $t = t_k$ for some $k$, $d[M,M]_t = 4(X_t - X_{t^{\ast \ast}})^2 d[X, X]_t$, where
$t^{\ast \ast} := \max \{ t_i \in \mathcal{G} \colon t_{i+1} \leq t \}$. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, and thanks for doing such a good job with the notation to make things clear for me!